# Tex Live Utility (Mac) not running automatic updates

Tags: texlive

I'm on El Capitan (10.11.5) and Tex Live 2016. I've noticed that Tex Live Utility is not running the scheduled updates (I have set them to weekly), it shows no notification on available updates. It updates fine manually.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.googlecode.mactlmgr.update_check.plist ; launchctl list |grep mactlmgr` in Terminal?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 mo  staff  668 28 jun 21:16 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.googlecode.mactlmgr.update_check.plist
- 1 com.googlecode.mactlmgr.update_check`

Comment: Okay, it's loaded and should be executing on schedule. Try `/usr/bin/python ~/Library/Application\ Support/TeX\ Live\ Utility/update_check.py`

Comment: `@AdamMaxwell` I get this `/usr/bin/python ~/Library/Application\ Support/TeX\ Live\ Utility/update_check.py
update_check.py: no tlmgr path set; TeX Live update check will not proceed`

Comment: Thanks, that's the one El Capitan path change that I missed. Should be fixed in the beta that I just uploaded. https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases/download/1.25b2/TeX.Live.Utility.app-1.25b2.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug, and should be fixed in the latest version of TeX Live Utility, (1.26, released today).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving a note for the author/maintainer on the TeX Live Utility (TLU) mailing list. See <http://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tlu>